# Why do some negative numbers produce weird characters with fontenc package?

Tags: fonts

This

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % comment-out this line to fix it

\newcommand{\ctype}[1]{\PYG{k+kt}{\texttt{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|r|r|}
\hline
    Type & Bits & Bytes & Minimum & Maximum \\ \hline
    \ctype{int8\_t} & 8 & 1 & -128 & 127 \\ \hline
    \ctype{int16\_t} & 16 & 2 & -32,768 & 32,767 \\ \hline
    \ctype{int32\_t} & 32 & 4 & −2,147,483,648 & 2,147,483,647 \\ \hline
    \ctype{int64\_t} & 64 & 8 & −9,223,372,036,854,775,808 & 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

produces this

[image]

I include `fontenc` to fix "Font shape * undefined" warnings, but it garbles some of the negative numbers?

Why is `fontenc` having this effect, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Because your `−` in the last two rows is U+2212, which in UTF-8 is input as `<E2><88><92>` and T1 encoded fonts happen to have `â`, `Ĺ` and `Š` at those locations. Without `fontenc` you get no output, but warnings about missing characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is extended comment:

I wonder how is possible that `-` sign has different characters in the first two rows and last two rows in the OP MWE. In the following MWE I only retype `-` characters (and also consider table formatting of *egreg* second example) and it works without `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}` and with and without `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{
>{\color{purple}}r
                 S[table-format=2.0]
                 S[table-format=1.0]
                 S[table-format=-19.0]
                 S[table-format= 19.0]
                   }
\toprule
\verb+int8_t+  & 8  & 1 & -128                 & 127                 \\  
\midrule
\verb+int16_t+ & 16 & 2 & -32768               & 32767               \\  
\verb+int32_t+ & 32 & 4 & -2147483648          & 2147483647          \\  
\verb+int64_t+ & 64 & 8 & -9223372036854775808 & 9223372036854775807 \\ 
\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I use WinEdt for editor preset to `utf8` encodiding, if this matter.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

The characters `−` in the last two rows are U+2212, which in UTF-8 is input as `<E2><88><92>` and T1 encoded fonts happen to have `â`, `Ĺ` and `Š` at those locations. Without `fontenc` you get no output, but warnings about missing characters.

Use also `inputenc`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-} % if U+2212 slips in

\newcommand{\ctype}[1]{\texttt{#1}}

\sisetup{group-separator={,}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  |l|
  S[table-format=2.0]|
  S[table-format=1.0]|
  S[table-format=-19.0]|
  S[table-format=19.0]|
}
\hline
Type & {Bits} & {Bytes} & {Minimum} & {Maximum} \\ \hline
\ctype{int8\_t} & 8 & 1 & -128 & 127 \\ \hline
\ctype{int16\_t} & 16 & 2 & -32768 & 32767 \\ \hline
\ctype{int32\_t} & 32 & 4 & −2147483648 & 2147483647 \\ \hline
\ctype{int64\_t} & 64 & 8 & −9223372036854775808 & 9223372036854775807 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

(I removed `minted` because the definition of `\ctype` gave errors.)

[image]

Just for improvement, loading `booktabs` and changing the table into

```
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=1.0]
  S[table-format=-19.0]
  S[table-format=19.0]
  @{}
}
\toprule
Type & {Bits} & {Bytes} & {Minimum} & {Maximum} \\
\midrule
\ctype{int8\_t} & 8 & 1 & -128 & 127 \\
\ctype{int16\_t} & 16 & 2 & -32768 & 32767 \\
\ctype{int32\_t} & 32 & 4 & −2147483648 & 2147483647 \\
\ctype{int64\_t} & 64 & 8 & −9223372036854775808 & 9223372036854775807 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

I also removed the setting for `group-separator`, which leaves the default thin space:

[image]

Comment: Why wouldn't it be better to just change each `−` to `-`?

Comment: @naught101 Certainly recommendable, but the character U+2212 might slip in from copy-paste and it may be difficult to find it.

Comment: That's exactly what happened.